# how to write conditions that define what color each point should be

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is an example data as @ Gregor suggested

```
df = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))
```

but I want to plot left part of plot (below zero in another color) and right part of the figure in another color

So I tried to plot it with ggplot but I am stuck , any suggestion?

```
g <- ggplot(data=df, aes(x=df[,1], y=df[,2])) +
  geom_point() +
  xlim(c(-2, 2)) + ylim(c(0,8)) +
  xlab("my x axis") + ylab(" my y axis") +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=16)))
g
```

what I want is to be able to plot it like this using ggplot

Comment: First, use unquoted column names inside `aes()`. ggplot has a data argument so you don't have to keep retyping the name of your data frame (and doing so can cause bugs!). Change your `aes()` to this: `aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = -log10(pvalue), color = log2FoldChange < 0)`.

Comment: @Gregor that is right Gregor but it only change the entire points to red and blue , I want to be able to apply all those changes in the first option with different colours in left and right , is this clear? or I am confusing you?

Comment: Also, in the future, I'd encourage you to provide **minimal** reproducible examples. You don't need to share 160,000 rows of data in a gist to ask the question *"How do I make points less than 0 a different color"*. You could use `df = data.frame(x = rnorm(10), y = rnorm(10))` for that. Or if you really like your data structure, `dput(droplevels(head(res, 10)))`.

Comment: Yes, you are confusing me. I read the words you wrote: *"but I want to plot left part of plot (below zero in another color) and right part of the figure in another color"* and I showed you how to do that.

Comment: If you want to pick the colors, `+ scale_color_manual(values = c("orange", "green"))`.

Comment: @Gregor I am sorry! what I want to do, if you plot the first option. it makes three colours , red, green and yellow for both sides. I want to make red green yellow for right side but for example pink, grey and orange for the left side.

Comment: @Gregor I tired the scale_color_manual but does not do what I want. it always makes two sides

Comment: Just add a column to your data that is a factor indicating the category. Use `ifelse()`, e.g., `res$my_grouping = with(res, ifelse(pvalue < 0.5 | log2FoldCount > 1, ifelse(pvalue < 0.5 & log2FoldCount > 1, 'both', 'one), 'neither'))`, then `aes(...,color = my_grouping)`. You can make your conditions as complicated as you would like. All you need is a column in the data indicating what grouping each row belongs to, and to color by that column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay. Let's be clear that this isn't a `ggplot` question at all, but a question of how to write conditions that define what color each point should be.

Starting with your original color scheme - I think I've correctly interpreted it as this

```
res$my_grouping = with(res, ifelse(pvalue < 0.5 | abs(log2FoldChange) > 1, ifelse(pvalue < 0.5 & abs(log2FoldChange) > 1, 'both', 'one'), 'neither'))
```

Now let's paste on on whether it is positive or negtiave:

```
res$my_grouping = paste(ifelse(res$log2FoldChange < 0, 'neg', 'pos'), res$my_grouping, sep = ', ')
```

Then plot:

```
ggplot(data=res, aes(x = log2FoldChange, y = -log10(pvalue), color = my_grouping)) +
  geom_point() +
  xlim(c(-2, 2)) + ylim(c(0,8)) +
  labs(x = "log2 fold change", y = "-log10  p-value", color = 'key') +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(shape=16)))
```

Yielding this:

[image]

You can customize the color values using `scale_color_manual`.